# LIME gives this error "classifier models without probability scores" in python

Tags: python, nlp, lime

it is my first time to use LIME and i have never used any interpretation technique before.

most likeley i am doing something wrong but i cannot figure out what is it.

I tried googling and go through SOF question to find the way to resolve this but did not find anything that can help me.

my dataset **df_reps** looks like this

```
Toyota Horse Toyota Gear... Mazda Night King
Green Mazda King Toyota ... Blue Mazda Toyota
...
...
Gear Tyre Toyota Geaer ... Horse Blue Park
Laptop Invoice Toyota ...  Horse Mango Kitkat
```

and labels to predict, is whether the customer approved of not so the labels are only 0 and 1

Here is my code

```
def BOW(df):
  CountVec = CountVectorizer() # to use only  bigrams ngram_range=(2,2)
  Count_data = CountVec.fit_transform(df)
  Count_data = Count_data.astype(np.uint8)
  cv_dataframe=pd.DataFrame(Count_data.toarray(), columns=CountVec.get_feature_names_out(), index=df.index)  # <- HERE
  return cv_dataframe.astype(np.uint8)

df = BOW(df_reps)
y = df_Labels    # this is either 0 or 1
X = df
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=100)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

I converted text into tabular format using BOW

therefore, i will using
# Here is the part for LIME

```
explainer = LimeTabularExplainer(X_train.values, feature_names=X_train.columns, verbose=True, mode='classification')
exp = explainer.explain_instance(X_test.values[1], clf.predict, num_features=10000)
```

but i am getting this error

> NotImplementedError: LIME does not currently support classifier models
> without probability scores. If this conflicts with your use case,
> please let us know: https://github.com/datascienceinc/lime/issues/16

Comment: From memory you don't / cannot pass `clf.predict` - you either pass `clf.predict_proba` or you implement your own function that returns the probabilities not the actual predictions

Comment: See cell 24 of https://marcotcr.github.io/lime/tutorials/Tutorial%20-%20continuous%20and%20categorical%20features.html for an example `predict_fn` and its usage in 27

Comment: @DavidWaterworth that worked, put it in an answer so i can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LimeTabularExplainer` requires probabilities, not predictions. So instead of passing `clf.predict` you need to either pass `clf.predict_proba` or a wrapper function that returns probabilities from features. For example based on [this](https://marcotcr.github.io/lime/tutorials/Tutorial%20-%20continuous%20and%20categorical%20features.html) tutorial:

```
predict_fn = lambda x: rf.predict_proba(encoder.transform(x))
exp = explainer.explain_instance(X_test, predict_fn)
```